# GitHub desktop not logging out of old account

Tags: github-desktop

Hi everyone I am getting a real weird error. A while back I started a Github account from an old email and wasn't active with and forgot about. Lately, I have opened a new github account with a different email that has all my current projects.

I had github desktop installed (older version) but like my old account I never really used. So I reopened it to access my new account but it is still connect to my old account. I logged out from the options and signed in via my new account through the web but the actual repositories and folders it is show are still from my old account.  I have tried updating, resinstalling and installing github desktop and signing out and signing back in various times and it is still connecting to my old account.

I am thinking there is still come connection with my Github desktop and my old account and need to somehow break the connection via the terminal but not aware of any command to do this.

If I am unable to break this connecting to my old account it seems to me like a major security issue with GitHut desktop. Hopefully thats not the case.

Does anyone have anyways of solving this issue or is this something that I should report to Github?

Answer (score 1):

This also happens when trying to log out from Git Bash, you have to go to "Control Panel" > "User Accounts" > "Credential Manager" > "Windows Credentials" and look for the application. Then, remove the credentials of Github. Hope this is usefull.